# How to create segments/lines by inputting coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, line

I have a set of coordinates and I wisht to recreate them in GIS. Basically, I am following from a paper based sketch map of maritime delimitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options. You'll want to consider how many points you have, and how much of the in-progress data you want to save/be able to edit along the way.

One would be to create a table out of your coordinate pairs, bring that table into Arc, create an XY event layer out of it, then digitize a line between the resulting points.

Another would be to start your create line tool and right-click or hit F6 to choose absolute X,Y where you can just type in the coordinates as you go. Or do you have bearings and distances, not coordinate pairs? If so, once you create the first point the same right-click menu will allow direction/length inputs along with a few other options.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you, Chris that was very helpful.